# Azure SQL - Code works locally but not on Azure

Tags: c++, azure, azure-sql-database

We are trying to check a scenario before displaying a pop-up message.  The code below works great from Visual Studio but not from Azure after being published.  Both are pointing to the same Azure SQL database.

```
            PTO objPTOExist = db.PTOes.Where(p =>
            (p.UserId == model.UserId && p.StartDate <= model.StartDate && model.StartDate <= p.EndDate && p.PTOId != model.PTOId)
            || (p.UserId == model.UserId && p.StartDate <= model.EndDate && model.EndDate <= p.EndDate && p.PTOId != model.PTOId)
            || (p.UserId == model.UserId && model.StartDate <= p.StartDate && p.StartDate <= model.EndDate && p.PTOId != model.PTOId)
            || (p.UserId == model.UserId && model.StartDate <= p.EndDate && p.EndDate <= model.EndDate && p.PTOId != model.PTOId)
            || (p.Name == "Holiday" && p.StartDate <= model.StartDate && model.StartDate <= p.EndDate && p.PTOId != model.PTOId)
            || (p.Name == "Holiday" && p.StartDate <= model.EndDate && model.EndDate <= p.EndDate && p.PTOId != model.PTOId)
            || (p.Name == "Holiday" && model.StartDate <= p.StartDate && p.StartDate <= model.EndDate && p.PTOId != model.PTOId)
            || (p.Name == "Holiday" && model.StartDate <= p.EndDate && p.EndDate <= model.EndDate && p.PTOId != model.PTOId)
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

I know I can make the code simpler but that also had bad results on Azure even though it works locally.

Thank you for any insight as to why Azure behaves differently.

Comment: what specifically happens?